# Determine system architecture

Tags: c#, .net, windows

What methods of what class in sytem offer information over whether my current system is 32 or 64 bits ? I'd like to determine the memory delivered once an object is saved on the system, for example, 4KB each for my current Intel DualCore 32 bit XP OS

Comment: Didn't you mean 4 bytes? The question is a little confusing to be able to answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx) to determine your system architecture, but it's unclear what you mean by "the memory delivered once an object is saved on the system".

If you're talking about when data is saved on your hard drive, then what you're referring to is the *block size* of your hard drive (incidentally, 4096B or 4K, as you describe is the default block size for Windows NTFS volumes). If this is the case, then that is not related to your processor in any way; that's a formatting option for a particular partition on a hard drive. I am not aware of a .NET mechanism for checking that.